# Активация радиокнопок при анимации слайдера

Tags: css3

Доброго времени суток. Имеется слайдер сделанный на CSS3, 3 изображения, использую анимацию 15 сек, infinite. Каждая картинка стоит 3 сек и затем за 2 сек. уходит в лево, за ней встает другая, и т.д. Хочу сделать в низу под слайдером три кружка и например когда в главном экране первый слайд то закрашивался первый круг, когда второй слайд то закрашивается второй круг и т.д. Можно ли это реализовать с помощью css3? Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста.

```css
#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: visible;
 width: 960px;
}

#content-slider {
 width:100%;
 height:360px;
 margin:10px auto 0;
}

#slider {
 background: #000;
 border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 height: 320px;
 width: 680px;
 margin: 40px auto 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

#mask {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 320px;
}

/*Стили для #active*/
#active {
 width: 680px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-align: center;
 outline: 1px solid red;
}

#active label {
 border: 2px solid red;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #bbb;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin-right: 5px; 
}

#active label:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid red; 
}


/*Конец стили для #active*/

#slider article{
 right: -680px;
 position: absolute;
}

#slider .firstanimation {
 animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
}

#slider .secondanimation {
 animation: cycletwo 15s linear infinite;
}

#slider .thirdanimation  {
 animation: cyclethree 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cycle {
 /*Стоит 3 секунды*/
 0%{left: 0}
 20%{left: 0; opacity: 1} /*3сек = 20%*/
 /*уход 2 секунды*/
 34%{left: -680px;opacity: 1} /*2 сек = 13%*/
 54%{left: -680px;opacity: 1}
 /*уход в право 2сек и стоит 3 сек*/
 67%{left: 680px;opacity: 0; z-index: -1}
 87%{left: 680px;opacity: 0; z-index: 0}
 100%{left: 0px;opacity: 1; z-index: 1}
}

@keyframes cycletwo {
 /*Стоит 3 секунды*/
 0%{left: 680px; opacity: 1; z-index: 1}
 20%{left: 680px; opacity: 1; z-index: 1} /*3сек = 20%*/
 34%{left: 0; opacity: 1} /*3сек = 20%*/
 54%{left: 0;opacity: 1}
 67.001%{left: -680px;opacity: 1}
 87.002%{left: -680px; opacity: 0}
 /*96%{left: 680px; opacity: 0}*/
 100%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
 /*уход 2 секунды*/

}

@keyframes cyclethree {
 /*Стоит 3 секунды*/
 34%{left: 680px; opacity: 1; z-index: -1}
 54%{left: 680px; opacity: 1;z-index: 0} /*3сек = 20%*/
 67%{left: 0px;opacity: 1;z-index: 0}
 87%{left: 0px;opacity: 1; z-index: 0}
 100%{left: -680px;opacity: 1}

}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="">
 <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
 <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
 <div class="container">
  <div id="content-slider">
   <div id="slider"><!--Контейнер для слайдера-->
    <div id="mask"> <!--mask-->
     <article id="first" class="firstanimation">
   
      <img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="Cougar">
      
      <div class="tooltip"><h1>Cougar</h1></div>
     </article>
     
     <article id="second" class="secondanimation">
      <img src="images/img_2.jpg" alt="Lions">
      <div class="tooltip"><h1>lions</h1></div>
     </article id="third" class="thirdanimation">
     
     <article id="third" class="thirdanimation">
      <img src="images/img_3.jpg" alt="Snowalker">
      <div class="tooltip"><h1>Snowalker</h1></div>
     </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="active">
 <label for="slide1" class="radioFirst"></label>
 <label for="slide2" class="radioSec"></label>
 <label for="slide3" class="radioThree"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: А где у вас `#active` в `html`?

Comment: Просто не надо делать кружки радиобаттонами - пусть будут просто цветными кружочками.

Comment: А если я хочу что бы по нажатию пользователем например на третий кружок, анимацию останавливалась и слайдер показывал третье изображение, если нажал на второй то второе и т.д.

Comment: input[type="radio"]{display:none}, next input[type="radio"]:before{your style} or use formstyler.js

Comment: Artem Gorlachev, вставил элемент с id active

Comment: Qwertiy, а если например нужно по нажатию по первому кружку, анимация останавливалась и слайд показывал первую картинку, если на вторую то вторая и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все с помощью '`~`':

```
#slide1:checked~.container #first,
#slide2:checked~.container #second,
#slide3:checked~.container #third{
  ...
}
```

```css
#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: visible;
 width: 960px;
}

#content-slider {
 width:100%;
 height:360px;
 margin:10px auto 0;
}

#slider {
 background: #000;
 border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 height: 320px;
 width: 680px;
 margin: 40px auto 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

#mask {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 320px;
}

/*Стили для #active*/
#active {
 width: 680px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-align: center;
 outline: 1px solid red;
}

#active label {
 border: 2px solid red;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #bbb;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin-right: 5px; 
}

#active label:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid red; 
}


/*Конец стили для #active*/

#slider article{
 right: -680px;
 position: absolute;
}

#slider .firstanimation {
 animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
}

#slider .secondanimation {
 animation: cycletwo 15s linear infinite;
}

#slider .thirdanimation  {
 animation: cyclethree 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cycle {
 /*Стоит 3 секунды*/
 0%{left: 0}
 20%{left: 0; opacity: 1} /*3сек = 20%*/
 /*уход 2 секунды*/
 34%{left: -680px;opacity: 1} /*2 сек = 13%*/
 54%{left: -680px;opacity: 1}
 /*уход в право 2сек и стоит 3 сек*/
 67%{left: 680px;opacity: 0; z-index: -1}
 87%{left: 680px;opacity: 0; z-index: 0}
 100%{left: 0px;opacity: 1; z-index: 1}
}

@keyframes cycletwo {
 /*Стоит 3 секунды*/
 0%{left: 680px; opacity: 1; z-index: 1}
 20%{left: 680px; opacity: 1; z-index: 1} /*3сек = 20%*/
 34%{left: 0; opacity: 1} /*3сек = 20%*/
 54%{left: 0;opacity: 1}
 67.001%{left: -680px;opacity: 1}
 87.002%{left: -680px; opacity: 0}
 /*96%{left: 680px; opacity: 0}*/
 100%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
 /*уход 2 секунды*/

}

@keyframes cyclethree {
 /*Стоит 3 секунды*/
 34%{left: 680px; opacity: 1; z-index: -1}
 54%{left: 680px; opacity: 1;z-index: 0} /*3сек = 20%*/
 67%{left: 0px;opacity: 1;z-index: 0}
 87%{left: 0px;opacity: 1; z-index: 0}
 100%{left: -680px;opacity: 1}
}



input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;
}

#slide1:checked~#active .radioFirst,
#slide2:checked~#active .radioSec,
#slide3:checked~#active .radioThree {
  background: #000;
}


/* Управление слайдами */
#slide1:checked~.container #first,
#slide2:checked~.container #second,
#slide3:checked~.container #third{
  animation: none;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="">
 <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
 <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
  
 <div class="container">
  <div id="content-slider">
   <div id="slider"><!--Контейнер для слайдера-->
    <div id="mask"> <!--mask-->
     <article id="first" class="firstanimation">   
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/777/fff&text=sl1" alt="Cougar">      
      <div class="tooltip"><h1>Cougar</h1></div>
     </article>
     
     <article id="second" class="secondanimation">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/ccc/fff&text=sl2" alt="Lions">
      <div class="tooltip"><h1>lions</h1></div>
     </article id="third" class="thirdanimation">
     
     <article id="third" class="thirdanimation">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/ddd/fff&text=sl3" alt="Snowalker">
      <div class="tooltip"><h1>Snowalker</h1></div>
     </article>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  
<div id="active">
 <label for="slide1" class="radioFirst"></label>
 <label for="slide2" class="radioSec"></label>
 <label for="slide3" class="radioThree"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Елена, доброго дня. Спасибо вам за ответ.

Comment: А возможно сделать так, что бы вместе с анимацией, менялся фон у лэйбла на черный, например через 3 секунды когда первый слайд уходит в лево, на его место встает второй слайд и в этом момент поменялся фон у второго лейбла на черный, для этого нужно делать отдельную анимацию для лейблов и назначить им такие же ключевые кадры как и для слайдов?

Comment: Да нужно делать отдельную анимацию и для лейблов с такими же ключевыми кадрами.

Comment: Elena Semenchenko спасибо.